# Python trivia game getting questions and answers off a website

Tags: beginner, python-3.x, game

Here is my code that I recently made (I am a beginner). I used BeautifulSoup and Requests to get the data of [this website](https://www.scarymommy.com/best-trivia-questions-answers). Please read over my code and tell me how to improve it. Thanks.

```
import random
import time
from os import system
import keyring
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def getdata(url):
    headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"}  
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    return r.text
def main():
    print('This is trivia, made by MY_NAME. Have fun!')
    print()
    while True:
        try:
            amount = int(input('How many questions would you like to answer? '))
            print()
        except ValueError:
            print()
            print('Must be a natural number.')
            print()
        else:
            if amount < 10 or amount > 145:
                print('Must be a natural number above 10 and less than 145.')
                print()
            else:
                break
    htmldata = getdata('https://www.scarymommy.com/best-trivia-questions-answers/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')
    q = str(soup.find_all(text=True))
    questions = []
    answers = []
    for x in range(1, amount + 1):
        question_index = q.find(f'{x}. ')
        next_index = q.find(f'{x+1}. ')
        to_add = q[question_index:next_index]
        to_add = to_add.replace("', '", '')
        to_add = to_add.replace('\n', '')
        questions.append(to_add[0:-1])
    for x in range(amount):
        unsplit = questions[x]
        split = unsplit.split(' Answer: ')
        que = split[0]
        que = que.replace(f'{x+1}. ', '')
        ans = split[1]
        ans = ans.replace('.\\', '')
        ans = ans.replace('\\n', '')
        ans = ans.replace('\\', '')
        answers.append(ans)
        questions[x] = que

    music = "/Users/XIA/Desktop/Python/Projects/Trivia/Music/intro_music.wav"
    system("afplay " + music)
    hisc_nme = keyring.get_password('trivia', 'hi')
    hisc_sce = keyring.get_password('trivia', 'sc')
    print()
    print('You will answer {} questions within 15 seconds, and the faster you answer, the more point\'s you\'ll get.'.format(len(questions)))
    print('Right now, {} has the high score of {}.'.format(hisc_nme, hisc_sce))
    print('Good luck, and have fun!')
    print()
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        cor_count = 0
        score = 0
        count = 0
        choices = list(range(len(questions)))
        for x in range(0, len(questions)):
            quest = random.choice(choices)
            choices.remove(quest)
            start = time.time()
            answer = input(questions[quest] + ' ').lower()
            end = time.time()
            Canswer = answers[quest]
            pCanswer = Canswer
            Canswer = Canswer.lower()
            time_took = end - start
            if answer != Canswer.strip():
                print('Wrong!')
                count += 1
                print('Your current score is {}.'.format(score))
                print('The correct answer was {}.'.format(pCanswer))
                print()
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print('Correct!')
                cor_count += 1
                count += 1
                print('You took {} seconds.'.format(round(time_took)))
                score += 1 + round((15/(time_took)))
                print('Your current score is {}.'.format(score))
                print()
                time.sleep(1)
        print('You got {} out of {} right. Your final score is {}.'.format(cor_count, count, score))
        if int(score) > int(hisc_sce):
            print('New high score!')
            new_name = input('Enter your name to be saved as the high score: ')
            keyring.set_password('trivia', 'hi', new_name)
            keyring.set_password('trivia', 'sc', str(score))
        again = input('Play again (y/n): ')
        if again.lower() != 'y':
            print('Goodbye!')
            system('say -v Victoria Please do not be salty and rage quit.')
            break
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly: this isn't a particularly useful application of scraping. You're scraping static content. You'd be better off literally copying and pasting that content into a local, hand-generated JSON file distributed with your game (while also including copyright attribution to the original source).

Do that, split up your mega-`main` into several different functions, and you'll be well on your way to sanity.