# Short function to check if an entered answer is close to a correct one

Tags: beginner, python-3.x

I had this [trivia game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/261387/python-trivia-game-getting-questions-and-answers-off-a-website), and from the review I got I improved my game. One of the improvements I made was this short function, to check the correctness of an answer (so if the correct answer was "Yellowstone park in Wyoming", "Yellowstone park" could be accepted. The code I have below works, but I would like it to be smarter, as the current code is simple. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
def check(answer, correct, percentage):
    matches = 0
    if len(answer) < len(correct):
        for x in range(len(answer)):
            if answer[x] == correct[x]:
                matches += 1
            total = len(correct)
    else:
        for x in range(len(correct)):
            if answer[x] == correct[x]:
                matches += 1
            total = len(answer)
    matches_percentage = (matches/total * 100)
    if matches_percentage >= percentage:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: the requirements are not clear enough. e.g. will "park in" be a good answer in your example? is the order of the words important? e.g. will "Wyoming Yellowstone" have the same rank as "Yellowstone Wyoming"? define better requirements and then the implementation can be discussed.

Comment: Take a look at [`difflib.SequenceMatcher`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-examples) in the standard library.  It has a `ratio()` method that returns a similarity score on a scale of 0.0 to 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

```py
    if matches_percentage >= percentage:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

is a verbose way of writing

```py
    return matches_percentage >= percentage
```

In `matches_percentage = (matches/total * 100)`, the parentheses are unnecessary.

You could compute `total` with just one `max(...)` expression:

```
total = max(len(correct), len(answer))
```

That just leaves comparing successive elements of `correct` and `answer` and counting matches until you run out of terms from one list or the other.  The `zip(...)` function is ideal for that.

```
matches = sum(a == b for a, b in zip(correct, answer))
```

I believe that reduces your function to four statements.